# dates ticks and labels on x-axis of a time series

Tags: r, date, time-series

I am trying for the last few hours to get the ticks of desired dates with labels as Month-Year on the x-axis of a time series plot. I have tried tons of things available on Stack and others but none worked out so far.

Below is an example of what I am trying so far. I am getting plot with x-axis as a numeric such as 2014.0, while I want it to be in the date format such as Jan-2014.

I am also trying to learn, in case of numeric year labels, how can I start my x-axis with 2014.1 instead of 2014.0 as the first month of my series is January. To get this I tried time function with offset=1 but it didn't work either. Please check below example

```
## dataframe and its time series
temp_df<- data.frame(date_temp= as.Date(dates_of_data), opp_temp= rnorm(29,mean = 100,sd=5))
temp_ts<- ts(temp_df[,2], start=2014, freq=12)

## plot
plot(temp_ts, axes=F, lwd=3, ylim=c(min(temp_ts),max(temp_ts)), xlab="", ylab="",type="l",col="black", main="")
points(temp_ts,pch=20,col="yellow")

## y-axis
axis(2, ylim=c(min(temp_ts),max(temp_ts)),col="black",lwd=2,line=1)
mtext(2,text="Y-axis count",line=3,col="black")

## x-axis
axis(1,pretty(range(time(temp_ts)),12))
mtext("Time - Year",side=1,col="black",line=2, lwd=3)
   ## axis(1,pretty(range(time(temp_ts, offset=1)),12))  -- didnt work either


temp_dates<- as.Date(as.yearmon(time(temp_ts))) 

axis(side=1, at=tt, labels = FALSE)
axis(side = 1, at = tt[ix], labels = labs[ix], tcl = -0.7, cex.axis = 1)

grid (NULL,NULL, lty = 6, col = "blue") 
dev.off()
```

[image: output of above]

Couple of things that I have tried so far includes

```
# 1.  par(xaxt="n")  ## didn't work
# 2.  axis(1, at=seq(from = min(temp_dates),to = max(temp_dates), by="month"), labels=format(temp_dates,"%Y-%b"),las=2)
```

Can you please tell me how to get x-axis labels as Jan-2014 (Month-Year)?

These are some of the link I went through as requested: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355042/label-x-axis-in-time-series-plot-using-r)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602801/set-x-axis-labels-to-dates-when-plotting-time-series)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927450/how-to-plot-a-certain-range-of-x-values-of-dates-and-times-error-invalid-xlim)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot)

**EDIT**: Below solution works perfectly using zoo library. However I have't been using zoo the whole time in my study and was interested more in doing the other way. Please correct what is wrong in the **previous** approach.

```
require(zoo)
dev.off()
x<- (zoo(temp_df$opp_temp, temp_df$date_temp))
plot(x, xaxt = "n")
x_times <- time(x)
ticks <- seq(x_times[1], x_times[length(x_times)], by = "month")
grid (5,5, lty = 6, col = "blue") 
axis(1, at = ticks, labels = format(x_times,"%Y-%b"),las=2, tcl = -0.3)
```

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for articles [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis)?

Comment: yes updated the question. I would never come to stack unless I haven't tried my best, or if working further on the question seems like a time waste.

Comment: Have you attempted a ggplot solution?

Comment: tbh, I have never used ggplot for ts.